# Epub: Footnotes breaking/not breaking

Tags: android, css, epub

My epub footnotes break into required number of lines in iBooks, but not in other readers (Blue Fire for Android, Adobe Digital Editions on iMac, etc.) where every single footnote is only in one line, which causes the text to disappear in the right margin of the screen.

- What might the problem be?  And ...
- How can I solve the problem?

All footnotes are placed at the end of chapters, before the epub makes a split to next chapter.

HTML:

```
        <p class="u_indryk">Det vil sige at ingen leder, uanset, hvor dygtig han eller hun måtte være, kan rumme de mange informationer, som man skal forholde sig til en kompleks beslutningsproces. Det skyldes, at enhver handling udspringer af en mental model og denne model, har en indbygget begrænsning, der især bliver synlig, når verden forandrer sig hurtigt. Grunden er, at vi altid vil have en træghed i forhold til at omstrukturere eller „omprogrammere“ vores mentale model hurtigt nok. En vigtig erkendelse er derfor, at de bedste beslutninger ikke altid træffes af enkeltpersoner, men af grupper, fordi antallet af „hjerner“ også øger den mentale kapacitet: </p>

            <p class="liste"><span class="char-style-override-2">▷&#9;</span>Den samme problemstilling kan ses fra mange forskellige synsvinkler.</p>
            <p class="liste"><span class="char-style-override-2">▷&#9;</span>Der er en øget mulighed for at forholde sig mere kreativt og mere kritisk. </p>

        <p class="u_indryk">En tredje vigtig erkendelse er desuden, at mange ledere godt nok er gode til at træffe hurtige beslutninger, men at disse beslutninger altid vil blive truffet inden for en relativ snæver mental spændvidde. Hvis vi skal træffe gode beslutninger, der i højere grad er innovative og som bryder med de logikker der er i forvejen, må vi acceptere, at det tager længere tid, fordi kreative processer ikke i samme grad kan „speedes op“. </p>
        <p class="u_indryk">Dette leder mig hen til det næste tema, der handler om „<span>kunsten at lede på kanten af kaos</span>“.</p>
        <p>&#160;</p>
        <div class="footnotes">
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-63" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-63-backlink">63</a>&#9;Steve Jobs: „You have to think differently.“ Foredrag på Macworld Expo 1997.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-64" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-64-backlink">64</a>&#9;www.google.dk/corporate/index.html</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-65" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-65-backlink">65</a>&#9;Alfred Josefsen: Noter fra konferencen Retorik.biz. „Når chefen tager ordet“. Afholdt af Rhetor, 2007.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-66" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-66-backlink">66</a>&#9;60-30-10-reglen formulerede jeg, efter at jeg havde gennemført en poll på linkedin, hvor jeg stillede spørgsmålet: „Hvilke temaer bør en karismatisk leder især fokusere på, når han kommunikerer sin vision og mission for fremtiden?“ Resultatet blev, at kun 7 % tillagde logos en betydning (ekspertviden, analyse, statistik, osv.), 30 % tillagde ethos en betydning (personlig dømmekraft og troværdighed), mens hele 63 % tillagde pathos (passion) en betydning. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-67" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-67-backlink">67</a>&#9;Citeret fra en tråd på linkedin, 2011.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-68" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-68-backlink">68</a>&#9;Sørensen, 2010.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-69" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-69-backlink">69</a>&#9;Der er naturligvis mange grunde til, at kommunikation og involvering ikke sker tilstrækkeligt, men jeg fremhæver især disse tre grunde. Disse bygger dels på forskningslitteraturen vedr. „participationsforskning“, dels på mine egne erfaringer, som topleder, mellemleder, konsulent og præstationstræner. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-70" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-70-backlink">70</a>&#9;Spørgsmålet blev stillet til ca. 3000 ledere og professionelle via linkedin-interesse&#173;grupper, 2012.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <p class="fodnote"><a id="footnote-2129-71" class="footnote-anchor" href="#footnote-2129-71-backlink">71</a>&#9;Miller,1956.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Paste us the html of your epub with the footnote part please

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be in your CSS. Check `div.footnotes`, `div.footnote`, and `p.footnote` for `white-space: pre` or `white-space: nowrap`, both of which will prevent lines from wrapping at the end of the page. Remove them, and you should be good.